# Anisotropy of the effective masses in semiconductors

Tags: solid-state-physics, mass, semiconductor-physics, crystals

Recently, I have received a referee report on my paper in which reviewer states the following: "... in all known direct band gap semiconductors  the electron effective mass is isotropic or has a negligible anisotropy in a comparison with the hole effective mass which can have much more pronounced anisotropy ". Is this statement true? If it is so, why does the hole effective mass have much more significant anisotropy than the electron effective mass?

Comment: Well, look at the curvature of the valence vs conduction bands in different directions to see if they are.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.